# Typeahead with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm trying to add autocomlete by typeahead to my project, but now it shows in the Dropdown `[object Object]`. Where am I wrong?

```
$scope.getUsers = function () {
        $scope.searchRequest = "/listaccounts.php?name=" + $scope.asyncSelected;
        console.log($scope.searchRequest);
        return $http.get($scope.searchRequest).then(function (response) {
            $scope.searchResults = response.data;
            return $scope.searchResults.records;
        });
    };

<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" ng-change="asyncSelected = asyncSelected.toLowerCase()" name="user" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" autocomplete="off" uib-typeahead="name for name in getUsers($viewValue)">
```

JSON looks like:

```
{"records":[{"name":"q2q23w"},{"name":"qantheman"},{"name":"qee"},{"name":"qit"},{"name":"qiwi"}]}
```

I need to show in the dropdown only names.

Comment: This should work with `uib-typeahead="user as user.name for user in getUsers($viewValue)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getUsers()` is returning an array of objects and typeahead seems to have problem with this. Either @hadiJz solution will work (I don't know) or you could return a list of strings from `getUsers()` by changing to:

```
return $scope.searchResults.records.map(function(record) { return record.name; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 uib-typeahead="name.name as name.name for name in getUsers($viewValue)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
 <input name="records" id="records" type="text" placeholder="enter a record" ng-model="selected" typeahead="record.name for record in records | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cumv8tv4/)**